# SQL Injection Prevention with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, omniauth

Using the omniauth plugin for Rails to find a user, I get a SQL Injection warning when I run brakeman on the following lines of code:

```
omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
user = User.where(omniauth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first
```

The SQL injection warning is:

> Possible SQL injection near line 15: User.where(request.env["omniauth.auth"].slice(:provider, :uid))
>   /app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb

How can I avoid this line of code being vulnerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
User.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth[:provider], omniauth[:uid])
```

Comment: do you mind if i ask what is the sqli risk with the slice? is it easy to retrieve the uid or something?